# How to create animated text using ExtJs

Tags: javascript, animation, text, extjs

Can any one please help to how to create animated text using ExtJs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some examples:

```
Ext.get("my-element-id").highlight();

Ext.get("my-element-id").fadeIn();
```

Easy. Check out the Ext.Fx class. It has many animation methods.

http://extjs.com/deploy/ext/docs/output/Ext.Fx.html

Comment: Things have changed in Ext JS 4: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.fx.Animator